# Tutorial for creating joomla template

Tags: templates, joomla-4.x

I read the tutorial about how to create a Joomla template from https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_basic_Joomla!_template , but when I scrutiny the Standard template bundled within Joomla 4.x (Cassiopeia), I saw a different way to create a Joomla template, It looks like an advanced way, can anyone give me a link to where I can learn something like this? a free tutorial is prioritized, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this link which may get you started. https://docs.joomla.org/J4.x:Cassiopeia_Template_Simplified_-_A_Case_Study